# Forever tool with mosquitto mqtt

Tags: shell, ubuntu, mosquitto, forever

I'm trying to make my mosquitto mqtt broker run constantly on my cloud instance with the forever tool using `forever start -l mqtt.log --append -c -sh /root/mqtt-sh.sh` and I already created the shell script by adding this `#!/bin/sh /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/broker.conf` to the mqtt-sh.sh conf file.
But this is the output I got:

```
help:    usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
help:
help:    Monitors the script specified in the current process or as a daemon
help:
help:    actions:
help:      start               Start SCRIPT as a daemon
help:      stop                Stop the daemon SCRIPT by Id|Uid|Pid|Index|Script
help:      stopall             Stop all running forever scripts
help:      restart             Restart the daemon SCRIPT
help:      restartall          Restart all running forever scripts
help:      list                List all running forever scripts
help:      config              Lists all forever user configuration
help:      set <key> <val>     Sets the specified forever config <key>
```

I also checked for the process in **forever list** but it's not there

Answer (score 0):

[Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) is for running NodeJS script files, not shell scripts.

Also there is no need for it with mosquitto, it will be installed as a systemd service which will can be set to start at boot and will run until the machine is shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hardillb. Please how can I do that?

Comment: With the standard tools, e.g. `service mosquitto start` to start, `systemctl enable mosquitto.service` to enable start on boot.